# creating a string character as a default parameter for function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good morning,

At the moment I am trying to create a histogram for class. I am now developing my skill as I have only been doing this for 2 months, and as I do know this is a website for professionals, and please you to excuse my lack of understanding.

```
def histo_print(times, dicerand, symbol='*'):
    print('%ds: %s' % (times, (dicerand * symbol)))
```

Question:

1. Is it possible to use a string as a default for "symbol"?
2. Would I be better off by assigning a default string character to the "symbol" variable outside of the loop? Then place an input function after assigning it?

I have not found a previous question asked that is similar to the one I am asking now. **Please if anyone is aware of where this question has been answered please post the url**, I prefer to research than be given the answer; however, I have not much time left to finish. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

This is the whole code:

```
def histo_print(times,dicerand,symbol):
    if symbol == none
    print ('%ds: %s' % (times,(dicerand * symbol)))

def rand(user_input):
    number = 0
    while number != user_input:
        die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        roll_total = die1 + die2


return roll_total

"""Introduction"""
print('Welcome to the Dice roll histogram.')

if num_rolls >= 1:
    """Adds one to user input because the for loop starts at one."""
    num_rolls += 1
    """Optional Secondary input based on if the number entered is greater than zero."""
    character = str(input('Please enter character:\n'))  # Additional input for user choice.
    """Unnecessary, just looks nice."""
    print('Dice roll histogram:\n')
    for i in range(1,num_rolls):
        rand(num_rolls)

        #Output
        histo_print(i, rand(num_rolls),character)

else:
    print('Invalid number of rolls. Try again.')
```

Comment: Which loop are you talking about ?

Comment: @polku I am using a "for" loop---

for i in range(1,num_rolls):
        rand(num_rolls)

        #Output
        histo_print(i, rand(num_rolls),character)

Comment: Post the piece of code from where the function is called and provide the desired output please. The website is not only for professionals btw.

Comment: You certainly can use a string (or any other object) as a default parameter. To me it seems to me that you are already using a string as a default parameter. What isn't working? It usually helps if you post your expected output and your actual output. Also, add the comment you posted here with code to your question by using the "edit" button.

Comment: @DamaniAPhilip post this code in your question by editing it, don't post it in the comments, it's hard to parse!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Would you prefer if I posted my whole code so everyone could understand? The program works it just that when I hit enter on the character option it registers a space instead of going to the default parameter. Ok no problem sir, I will do it now

Comment: @DamaniAPhilip post as much code as you think is necessary, but post it in the actual question, not the comments.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you again, I have posted everything so you can understand

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga you are a great person and I wish you all the best in your future endeavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes.  Yes, you can absolutely use a string value to pass off as a "default" in your function.  For starters, take a quick read here to avoid common gotchas ==> http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/ .  In your case, I would keep it as such.

Now for your next question, while you can absolutely place this "default" value in your for loop.  However, the rule of thumb is, for the sake of readability, place these default values in functions and override as needed.

Comment: I see this idiom with the default set to None from time to time, but I thought it was to prevent the notorious "surprising" behavior with mutable default arguments. Since strings are immutable, I doesn't understand the motivation in this case. For example, the `print` function has default parameters: `sep=' ', end='\n'`

Comment: Strings are immutable - string as a default argument is perfectly fine.

Comment: Both of you have made valid points.  No need to inject my cynical behavior in otherwise immutable objects.

Comment: heh cynical behavior.

Comment: @Carlos Thank you very very much, I have also saved that link.